# Join between a table and a recursive table

Tags: mysql, join

I've that two table, I know they are not well thinked but my client did this tables and I cannot change them.

```
TABLE A
id | codigoFatherTABLEB | codigoSonTABLEB 

TABLE B 
id | name | codigo | idPadre ( can be NULL and is related to id of the same table )
```

I try to have :

```
VIEWAB
idA | codigoFatherTABLEB | nameFatherTABLEB | codigoSonTABLEB | nameSonTABLEB
```

I don't know how to make the join to get the codigoSonTABLEB.

for exemple :

```
TABLE B 

5  Foo EFX55 NULL    
6  BAR EFJJL2 5    
7  WEL EFJJL2 1

TABLE A    
12 EFX55  EFJJL2
```

I want

```
VIEWAB
12 EFX55 Foo EFJJL2 BAR
```

Comment: before put a downvote could explain how I could improve my question

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  A.id,
  BFather.codigo,
  BFather.Name,
  BSon.codigo,
  BSon.Name
FROM
  TABLEA A 
  JOIN TABLEB BFather
    ON A.codigoFatherTABLEB = BFather.codigo
  JOIN TABLEB BSon
    ON A.codigoSonTABLEB = BSon.codigo
   AND BSon.idPadre = BFather.id
```

Comment: Hi Nathan thank for reply but , the theme is TableB could have several entries with the same codigo but not for the same father. With you join I will get the entry with the name "WEL"

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect this new requirement.